# Deleting a Plist Dictionary Item by Title Key from Shell Script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, safari, plist

I'm trying to create a shell script that will delete a top-level folder from Safari Bookmarks using Safari's Bookmarks.plist file by folder name. Unfortunately the only method I've found to delete the dictionary item with PlistBuddy or plutil is by index number.

Here's the basic structure:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>Children</key>
    <array>
        <dict> ... history ... </dict>
        <dict> ... bookmarks bar ... </dict>
        <dict> ... bookmarks menu ... </dict>
        <dict> ... reading list ... </dict>
        <dict> ... folder 1 ... </dict>

        <!-- Delete this item -->
        <dict>
            <key>Sync</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Data</key>
                <data>...</data>
                <key>ServerID</key>
                <string></string>
            </dict>

            <!-- By this key/value -->
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Delete This Folder</string>

            <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
            <string>WebBookmarkTypeList</string>
            <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
            <string>21D71C04-F58B-43ED-B02C-7D9A208CCEC0</string>
        </dict>

        <dict> ... folder 3 ... </dict>
    </array>
    <dict>...</dict>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>WebBookmarkFileVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
    <string>WebBookmarkTypeList</string>
    <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
    <string>892D35B5-DD40-418F-83D3-7AB77C2D9C03</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to delete the entire dictionary item in the first array with the `Title` value `Delete This Folder` since the items and index numbers can change all the time.

I can delete this item by index successfully in a couple of ways, including:

**PlistBuddy:**

```shell
PlistBuddy -c "delete :Children:5" /Users/myuser/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
```

**plutil:**

```shell
plutil -remove Children.5 /Users/myuser/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
```

But I haven't found the correct syntax — if it's possible at all — to delete by title with either of those utilities nor have I found another command line utility that can do it.

Alternatively, I'm not apposed to a two step process:

1. Query the plist file to find the title and return index number.
2. Delete by index number as above.

I'm not sure where to start with this though and I'm pretty sure `PlistBuddy`, `plutil` and `defaults read` don't have the capabilities search, count and return the value for me.

Thanks, any recommendations would be greatly appreciated, I've been searching and testing techniques for the last few hours without any luck.